# onclick event include the remaining space

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, css-position

In the following HTML code, when I click on text a message is shown. I need that `onclick` event include the white space on the right of text too.

```html
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<span class="list-group-item" type="button">
    <span class="label label-primary label-as-badge">3</span>
    <span class="label label-default label-as-badge">1</span>
    <span class="label label-success label-as-badge">0</span> 
    <span onclick="alert('you click me')">my text</span>  
</span>
```

**Update**

Since my words are ambiguous to some people, I show it by an image. The blue oval shows region of `onclick` operation. And the red oval shows the range that I want to expand this event. If user click in the red oval, this event must be activated.

[image]

Comment: What white space are you referring to?

Comment: @brenjt, I refer to any space inside the parent `span` but not filled by the last inner `span`

Comment: Its a difficult to understand what you trying to achieve, your try to get the empty textnode after "<span onclick="alert('you click me')">my text</span>" ?

Comment: You want a click on space that is *not* in the span to trigger the click event on the span? Maybe use a block element as the container, rather than an inline element, and put the click event on the container?

Comment: @sjm, please see my update.

Comment: @nnnnnn, i am not good at HTML and Js. I have no idea about what you suggest. Could you please provide the suggested code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a table like layout using display:table & display:table-cell on the elements and give the element 'width:100%' you want to take up the remaining space in the row

```html
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<span style="display:table;width:100%;" class="list-group-item" type="button">
    <span style="display:table-cell;" class="label label-primary label-as-badge">3</span>
    <span style="display:table-cell;" class="label label-default label-as-badge">1</span>
    <span style="display:table-cell;" class="label label-success label-as-badge">0</span> 
    <span style="display:table-cell;width:100%;background-color:#ccc;" onclick="alert('you click me')">my text</span>  
</span>
```